# How can i iterate in this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I need to catch every row , for example the data i have like this

```
       age state  point
Alice   20    NY     64
Bob     32    CA     92
```

I need to loop in every row with the values `Alice,20,NY,64` once time to make processing on it and then take the second row which is `Bob,32,CA,92` to make the same processing on it and so on

I tried this code but got wrong values

```
df = pd.read_csv("the file")
for i, j in df.iteritems():
    
    processing(j)
```

Comment: `iteritems` iterates over the columns and is deprecated. Try `iterrows` or `itertuples` and please consult the documentation first. All of this information is present there with examples

Comment: thanks for this noticement and helping but excuse me , does  iteritems method not working ?

Comment: If you explained exactly what processing you were trying to do you can probably get an answer which does it quite efficiently (possibly even without iterating).

Comment: Always tag pandas questions with pandas and python, they will get seen by far more people.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is to apply your processing-function to your dataframe.

The syntax for that is:

create example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': {'Alice': 20, 'Bob': 32}, 'state': {'Alice': 'NY', 'Bob': 'CA'}, 'point': {'Alice': 64, 'Bob': 92}})

def processing(row):
    print(row.name, row.age, row.state, row.point)

       age state  point
Alice   20    NY     64
Bob     32    CA     92
```

and then:

```
df.apply(processing, axis=1)
```

This applies the function processing on every row (axis=1) of your DataFrame.

In this example it just prints:

```
Alice 20 NY 64
Bob 32 CA 92
```